# Infimum and supremum of the set $Z = \left\{ \frac{m}{n}: m, n \in \mathbb{N} \space \land 4^n n^m < m^m < 27^n n^m \right\}$

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

The problem is to find supremum and infimum of set $$Z = \left\{ \frac{m}{n}: m, n \in \mathbb{N} \space \land \space4^n n^m < m^m < 27^n n^m \right\}$$

I have an answer to this question, infimum is $2$ and supremum is $3$ but I don't see how to actually do the problem, so I would like to ask for some help with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}4^nn^m<m^m&<27^nn^m \implies 4^{n/m}n<m<27^{n/m}n\\[1ex]
&\implies 4^{n/m}<m/n<27^{n/m}\\[1ex]
&\implies 4<(m/n)^{m/n}<27\\[1ex]
&\implies 2^2<q^q<3^3
\end{align}

where $\;q=m/n$.

Now, it is easy to see that the function $\;q\longmapsto q^q\;$ is strictly increasing for $q\geq 1/e$, and it is $\;\geq 1\;$ iff $q\geq1$. Hence, from the previous calculation we deduce that $\;2<q<3$. The bounds $2$ and $3$ are respectively $\;\it inf\;$ and $\;\it sup\;$ because

$$ \lim_{q\to2^+}q^q=2^2\qquad \text{and}\qquad \lim_{q\to3^-}q^q = 3^3.$$

Comment: Why did you deleted this answer? I lost some time answering this question (almost with the same steps) that I would have not spent if I would have seen that there was your answer first..

Comment: Sorry if I made you waste time (even if I do not consider it a waste of time, since I always learn something from each answer), but I made a mistake, and I realized it late.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n,m \ne 0$, let's manipulate the second condition of the elements of that set:
$$\begin{align}
4^n n^m < m^m < 27^n n^m & \iff 4^n < \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^m < 27^n \\[8pt]
& \iff 4^{\frac{n}{m}} < \frac{m}{n} < 27^{\frac{n}{m}}
\end{align}$$

Now, if you call for simplicity $a := \frac{m}{n}$ the last equation gives $$4^{\frac{1}{a}} < a < 27^{\frac{1}{a}}$$
that holds if and only if
$$2 < a < 3$$

With this conclusion we arrived to the following set:
$$Z := \left\{a \in \mathbb{Q} \ : \  2 < a < 3 \right\}$$